# create react app typescript css module not working

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, css-modules

When I want to import css module file into a component the compiler shows this error

```
ERROR in src/layouts/Menu/MenuTop/TabOne.tsx:11:20
TS2307: Cannot find module './TabOne.module.css' or its corresponding type declarations.
  > 11 | import styles from './TabOne.module.css'
```

But if I change it to something like this:

```
// @ts-ignore
import styles from './TabOne.module.css'
```

it works without any problem.

I'm using create-react-app v5 and recently I moved the project from js to ts using steps explained [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-typescript/) and I'm not sure if it's related to it or something else is not working as expected

start command:

```
react-scripts start
```

related dependencies in package.json file:

```
"react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
"react": "^18.2.0",
```

also the tsconfig.json file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "baseUrl": "src/",
    "strictNullChecks": true
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

Comment: add your `tsconfig.json` file   to your question ? it should be  created automatically for you

Comment: @monim I added my tsconfig file. it's the default file which create-react-app uses

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add `declare module "*.module.css";` to `declaration.d.ts` file in the project root folder .

then Add  **declaration.d.ts** to  **tsconfig.json**  by  changing  `"include": ["src"]`  to `"include": ["src", "declaration.d.ts"]`,

Comment: react-scripts has this declaration. Should we duplicate `declare` statements? Or we can use good old deprecated [triple-slash-reference in react-app-env](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76063668/8706090)?

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue here. The problem is caused by react-scripts.
Alternatively, to add declare module solution mentioned above, you could consider downgrading react-scripts from 5 to 4. While this may not be an option in your organization, I think it's worth mentioning.

"react-scripts": "5.0.0"
↓
"react-scripts": "4.0.3"

Answer (score 0):

You need to add typescript triple-slash-reference to any `d.ts` file inside `src/`

For some reason cra missed the `src/react-app-env.d.ts` file with content

```
/// <reference types="react-scripts" />
```